# Perturbations of the Metric in GR

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, perturbation-theory

I have been studying a bit of GR and am still a bit confused as how it works with perturbations of the metric or even in what norm the perturbation is meant to be understood.

For example, what happens to the Einstein field equations if we take the metric to be a small perturbation away from the Scwarzchild metric?

Comment: What exactly are you looking to find an answer to?

Comment: How are the Einstein field equations modified if one assumes that the metric is a perturbation of Schwarzchild spacetime?

Comment: Just search for "black hole perturbation theory" on the internet. There are various lectures and notes that should answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Einstein's equation is a fundamental law and cannot be changed. A perturbation means that a perturbation to stress energy tensor will result in a perturbation to the solution of Einstein's equation. For example, instead of considering the Schwarzschild geometry of the Sun, we want to look at the geometry of the solar system.

Comment: Also could I ask what it means to have a perturbation of Schwarzchild metric, does it mean the metric is a local perturbation of the Schwarzschild exterior region?

Comment: Yes, it just means that the metric is a little changed. For example, each planet will slightly change the Schwarzschild geometry surrounding the Sun.

Comment: I have one other question if you don't mind: I recently read of a result which was proved for a perturbations of the Schwarzchild exterior in a slab around a
null hypersurface $N_0$ which terminates at past null infinity.  I assume that this result is still not true for general perturbations of the Schwarzchild geometry as it would depend on whether such a null hypersurface exists in the geometry?

Comment: I think they are talking of the event horizon of a black hole, treated as a stable solution. This is a mathematical idealisation, because black holes must first form. They might be treating the formation of the black hole as a perturbation to the stable solution, which is not unreasonable, but a perturbative solution should only be taken to be an approximation for a limited time period.

Comment: Yes the actual wording is 'In fact, our result requires only a portion of a space-time,
which is a neighborhood of a past-directed outgoing null hypersurface N 0 which
emanates from the MOTS S0 and extends up to past null infinity'.  The author states that they proved the result for black hole spacetimes which are local perturbations about a neighbourhood of a (past-directed) shear-free outgoing null surface, I am trying to follow whether such a surface always exists in a black hole spacetime simply because it emanates from a marginally outer trapped surface contained in the spacetime.

Comment: Ah right, I've taken a look now and think I've understood, this is not an easy subject though.  Thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: I have a slightly silly question, if a metric has no off-diagonal components does that mean the perturbation of the metric will also have no off-diagonal components, as there is 'nothing to perturb' otherwise?

Comment: No, a pertubation means only a small change. I see no reason why a small change should not introduce off-diagonal components.

Comment: Ah right, that complicates what I was going to study hugely.  So one could have $h_{1 3 } $ not equal to  $0$ even if $g_{1 3 } = 0$?  Is it usually a reasonable assumption in application that this would be the case, or is this never assumed?

Comment: I can't tell you what others assume! But I do agree that when you get into the nitty-gritty, it becomes hugely complicated.

Comment: Yes this is more complicated than I first thought.  I was wondering if I could ask a quick question about notation.  If one has the future unit normal vector $n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g^{0 0}}}g^{0 \alpha} \partial_{\alpha}$, does that mean that $n_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g^{0 0}}}g^{0 1} \partial_{1}$?